# QML - Can not binding Combobox model to a variant list item

Tags: qt, combobox, model, qml, qtquick2

Can anyone help me solve this issue? I can't be binding a list variant to a combobox.

My code is here

```
Window {
  property var nameList: []
  id: mainWindow
  visible: true
  minimumWidth: 1024
  minimumHeight: 600
  width: minimumWidth
  height: minimumHeight

  ComboBox{
    id: cbo1
    currentIndex: 0
  }

  Binding{
    target: cbo1
    property: "model"
    value: nameList
  }

  Component.onCompleted: {
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        nameList.push(i)
        console.log("data: " + nameList[i])
    }
  }
```

Any help is my appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the binding to work, the property must change. Adding items to the list does not modify the reference of the list, so for binding the list never changed. The solution is to create a temporary list that will replace the original list:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        tmp.push(i)
    }
    nameList = tmp; // change property
}
```